# Inconsistent mgcv gam.check results

Tags: regression, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for cross validated, but I'm not sure where else to post it.

I've built a simple model using the `mgcv` package.

```
a <- gam(x ~ s(y), method="REML", data=dat100k)
```

However, when I run `gam.check(a)`, I get inconsistent output each time I run `gam.check(a)` with the same model.  k is considered OK in the first `gam.check(a)` call (although, k is close to edf and p is not very large), and on the second call k is considered too low according to the p-value. Is this normal?

Here is output from running gam.check(a) twice:

```
gam.check(a)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 8 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.04365533,0.04277738]
(score 407913 & scale 214.1436).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [4.001815,49713.04].
Model rank =  10 / 10 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                    k'  edf k-index p-value
s(y) 9.00 8.98       1    0.66

> gam.check(a)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 8 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.04365533,0.04277738]
(score 407913 & scale 214.1436).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [4.001815,49713.04].
Model rank =  10 / 10 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                    k'  edf k-index p-value  
s(y) 9.00 8.98    0.98    0.04 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: What happens if you use set.seed(12345) before each call to gam.check()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is due to the basis dimension test used in `gam.check()` being based on permutations of model residuals. These permutations are computed using a pseudo random number generator; by design each time you call `gam.check()` (or directly `k.check()` itself), a different set of permutations are produced, which subtly alters the p-value of the permutation tests performed.

If you set the seed of the pseudo random number generator before calling `gam.check()` or `k.check()`, the results become consistent:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=200)
b <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat)

set.seed(1)
k.check(b)
set.seed(1)
k.check(b)
```

which produces:

```
> set.seed(1)
> k.check(b)
      k'      edf   k-index p-value
s(x0)  9 2.318172 0.9959628  0.4950
s(x1)  9 2.305695 0.9693887  0.3225
s(x2)  9 7.654740 0.9605490  0.2825
s(x3)  9 1.232618 1.0372831  0.6850
> set.seed(1)
> k.check(b)
      k'      edf   k-index p-value
s(x0)  9 2.318172 0.9959628  0.4950
s(x1)  9 2.305695 0.9693887  0.3225
s(x2)  9 7.654740 0.9605490  0.2825
s(x3)  9 1.232618 1.0372831  0.6850
```

If you do a greater number of permutations than the default `n.rep = 400`, then all else equal the p-value should start to stabilise, but this comes at much greater computational cost.

I would also tret the output from this test (certainly the p-value) as just a guide. In your instance, the EDF of the smooth is almost at it's maximum possible value. Regardless of what the p-value of the simple, heuristic test is, I'd want to increase `k` (double it to `k = 20` in the s(...)` call in the formula) and see if the estimated smooth changes at all; does it use a larger EDF than the original fit?

Comment: Further to Gavin's excellent response, you can also check the help function for gam.check() here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-24/topics/gam.check.